# Trying to return the value of a particular cell based on the value of a cell in current table using LOOKUPVALUE

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to return `'Plant ID'` value based on the `'Material ID'` value in the current table (`Materials`) from another table (`MasterData`). I am using the `LOOKUPVALUE` function but I keep getting the error:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

The DAX code I am using:

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(MasterData[Plant ID], MasterData[Material ID], 'Materials'[Material ID])
```

My MasterData table looks like the following:

[image: PowerBI Table Screenshot]

Comment: It sounds like the same `Material ID` is associated with multiple `Plant ID` values in the `MasterData` table and the DAX doesn't know which one you want to return.

Comment: `LOOKUPVALUE()` requires a search_columnName field that has distinct values to look something up.  MasterData[Material ID]` is your search_columnName but has repeated values, hence the error.  To solve, the Lookup needs to use a field with distinct values.  That probably means creating a new table that has the equivalent of distinct `[Material ID]` in relation to `[Plant ID]`.

Comment: So the table where I am trying to input the relevant [Plant ID] associated with the [Material ID] has unique [Material ID]s in a column. All I want to is basically just grab the [Plant ID] associated with each unique [Material ID]. I want to refer to the [Material ID] in my current table and go into the MasterData table and grab the [Plant ID] from that row.

Answer (score 0):

"*All I want to is basically just grab the [Plant ID] associated with each unique [Material ID]*" ... since it's not clear how is your model wired. You can achieve this by creating a new table and connecting it back to your model.

Create a new table in the Data view and run this script.

```html
Table = 
GENERATE(
    VALUES(MasterData[Material ID]),
    VALUES(MasterData[Plant ID])
)
```

N -